# Why does oData return less users than Azure DevOps shows on organization users page

Tags: azure-devops, odata

When viewing `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_settings/users` the total users show approximately twice as many users than the oData query from Power BI `= Source{[Name="Users",Signature="table"]}[Data]`.

I would expect unfiltered datasets on both ends would show the same total count of users.

Any ideas why this discrepancy may exist?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, how about your puzzle? Does the below explanation and the doc section could help you solve the puzzle? Feel free to leave the comment if you still have any other issue or puzzle:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The total users show approximately twice as many users than the oData query from Power BI.**

First, refer to the below pic to see that where's the data for OData query come from:

[image]

OData query is a query used to report **Boards Data** for Azure DevOps (server and service). It could not get the data about org total users list since it just a query tool which for Boards, it can only query the data from **Boards**(In OData-preview, it add Builds query feature).

So, in your issue, the users which listed in the query result of `Source{[Name="Users",Signature="table"]}[Data]` is just the user who be `assigned to` by work item. That's why its count number is far less than your org total users number. Because the rest users who does not listed in the query result does not ever been assigned to by any work item. You can use azure devops query to verify it.

Due to: [Data available from Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-available-in-analytics?view=azure-devops).

Until now, OData does not support query the data outside Boards, such as what you want:query org users list. The only method to get users list is using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

As work around, for the method which integrated into power BI you can use to get the org users is [Custome Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/overview-of-power-bi-rest-api). But, since I am not too professional for Power BI, you can raise a new ticket for how to custome REST api in power BI.

Comment: Your answer explains the issue very well.  Thanks for links to help move me towards a proper solution.  Thanks again.